# Upper Bound on number of solutions to $ab \equiv 0 \pmod n$

Tags: number-theory

Does anyone have a good upper bound on the number of solutions to $ab \equiv 0 \pmod n$? If so, can anyone provide a proof for their bound?

Comment: Please elaborate abiessu, could you please provide a proof?

Comment: Can you please explain how every solution with $k$ that is not $0, 1$ is just repeating a  solution for $k = 1$?

Comment: Yes but the problem with this is that $c$ and $d$ need not generate distinct $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Perhaps you understood me wrong, please look at my comment in the other thread

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how that might help. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I promised: "Mark, yes, you're right, I have made an error of considering only equality, not the congruence, I'll remove my Answer within a few minutes.", and so I did. The (true :-) answer is more or less clear but at the moment hard to get it elegant enough.

Comment: Let $k$ be a divisor of $n$, and take all positive integers not greater than $\frac nk$ which are relatively prime with $n\setminus k$ and multiply each by $k$; this set of numbers can be the $a$ values.  Making the solution set distinct may take more work, but this method should produce all the possible solutions.

Comment: Now I've posted something like a new answer but definitely not an ultimate answer (sorry).

Comment: Infinitely many.  Or did you mean $0 \leq a < n$ and $0 \leq b < n$ or some other specification of the domain containing allowable $a$s and $b$s?

Answer (score 0):

> ***For starters***, I'll provide an **exact** formula. It will be not efficient though (not practical :-)) but it may provide a good introduction toward further progress.

I'll consider solutions which differ by the order to be different. Of course, we count the number of congruence classes $\mod n$. Also, let's exclude class $\ [0],\ $ it's only natural. This means that $\ [1]\ $ cannot appear as $\ a\ $ or $\ b\ $ of such solutions.

Let $\ d(n)\ $ be the number of natural (hence positive) divisors of $\ n.\ $ Let also

$$ D_n\ :=\ \{\,x\in\mathbb N: 1<x<n\,\ \mbox{and}
             \,\ x|n\,\}  $$
and
$$ E_n\ :=\ D_n\setminus\mathbb P\ $$

where $\ \mathbb P\ $ is the set of all primes.

Then the number of solutions is exactly

$$ S(n)\,\ :=\,\ (d(n)-2)^2\ -
        \ \sum_{k\in E_n}(|D_k|) $$
In other words,

$$ S(n)\,\ =\,\ (d(n)-2)^2\ +\ 2\cdot|E_n|\ -
        \ \sum_{k\in E_n}d(k) $$

> **REMARK.**   In the definition of the number of solutions $\ S(n)\ $ (the first formula) I didn't need $\ E_N\ $ at all, I could write there simply $\ D_n.\ $ However, this kind of *elegance* would obscure the computable meaning of $\ S(n)$.